# How can I display the content of my webpage in center using react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am designing a webpage for a desktop using react-bootstrap. I  have in my webpage logo, Main heading and form, and some links after the display of the form, I want to display all my content in the center of the webpage. How can I accomplish it using bootstrap flexbox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the most parent `div` or `element` in your app a `className` and apply `flexbox` properties to it.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center'>...</div> // <--------Most parent div-------->
  )
}
```

If you only want to `center` the content `horizontally` then only apply `justify-content` otherwise apply both.